# IP Camera working on lan but not on internet

Tags: ip, debugging

My IP cam model is `Genius 350TR`, I tested the cam at home on lan and internet and it worked. Then I shifted it to an office. It works on the office lan setup but I cannot connect to the ip cam from home.

The IP cam is configured for port `192.168.0.30:7070` and it has a port forwarded to `publicIP:7071`

When I `telnet` to that public IP it connects to that port.
However when I try to access the ip cam from a web browser it only shows me the configuration page and settings and the video is blank and it says connecting for some time and then says disconnected.
The cam is configured for HTTP on internet and UDP on Lan.

The office setup is  ISP ---> WifiRouter ---> PC With Wifi card ---> Switch ---> IP CAM

Is there a way to debug this problem?

Comment: Does the wifi router connect to the switch?

Comment: @GregAskew: No. The switch is connected to the ethernet connected of the PC with Wifi card. The Wifi and ethernet connections are bridged.

Comment: Wow, that actually works? ;-)

Comment: @GregAskew Lol! What did you expect?

Comment: @KevinBoyd: One would expect it not to work. The access point is not supposed to forward frames to a client unless the packet's hardware destination address is the address of one of its clients. Since the IP CAM is not a client of the WiFi router, it should not forward packets destined to it to the PC. This is why you have to configure WDS in *both* access points. (Likely, your PC is providing some unusual form of NAT where it rewrites the hardware addresses, much as some Wifi routers do in "client bridge" mode.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Now's that's what I didn't know! Thanks for the explanation!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is, that camera have video stream on another port. And if you don't have forwarded port for video stream too, you cannot see a video in the browser. In some cameras you can configure ports for video, then you can see, which port you have redirect too. If this camera don't have port in configuration, try `nmap` or some similar tool to scan, which port on the camera is opened...

EDIT:

You can see this port in HTML of web page, where is empty place for video... Try to use 'Ctrl+u' on this page in your web browser, this is usually shortcut for 'preview HTML', and try to search in the HTML code.

Comment: I recheced my camera settings and it shows 3 ports, HTTP (7070), RTSP(554) and stream(53). At the moment the HTTP port is forwarded but not RTSP and stream. Do those need to be forwarded too? Regarding nmap can it be nun on Windows?

Comment: You are know, which ports you have to redirect... :-) Stream port and RTSP port.

Comment: nmap works on windows... See http://nmap.org/download.html

Comment: Ok so my cam's IP is 192.168.0.30:7070, so for RTSP and Stream do I have to set port forwarding for that too in the wifi router?

Comment: Yes, you have to forward this ports too. You can try first only RTSP, and, if it will not works, try Stream too.

Comment: This is getting interesting Jan, In my wifi router  port forwarding page it shows ALL / TCP / UDP. so should I set protocol to ALL and for rtsp add 192.168.0.30:554 and forward it to the same public ip/port of publicIP:7071 ??

Comment: I have not yet checked, but I award the right answer for the awesome suggestion of nmap and also for the possible error in the system of not opening RTSP and Stream ports! Many Thanks!

Comment: BTW! The webpage uses an activeX control to connect to the cam? So I can't see any port settings there(in the web page source).

Comment: OK, you know ports from the configuration...

Comment: Jan, I can now view rtsp streams from the webcam. But in the earlier setup I could view stream on HTTP that doesn't work now I don't know why? Just wanted to ask what is the difference between RTSP port and Stream port. I know how to access the RTSP by using a url, but how do I access the stream port?

Comment: Please, try to forward: http port cam -> router:7071, 554 port cam -> router:554. Don't forward port 53, because it is the same port as DNS.

Comment: Thanks Jan!, I changed the port stream port number from 53 to a higher number(2222) and forwarded it. Do you think this is a security issue?? Is stream port not used by the IP cam at all?

Comment: In the UNIX world, the important port number are less than 1024. But there can be other services, which have port higher than 1024, say 5060 for SIP... Try use a google whith question `IP port xyz`, you will see, if it is free...

Answer (score 0):

As per an earlier answer, you need two unique forwarded ports for each camera and each element. So RTSP (normally port 554), HTTP (normally port 80) and Video Port (normally port 90) each need to be unique for each camera and forwarded through the router ... even if the calling port is only HTTP, the responses and 'dialogue' will include the rtsp and video, so they too need to be unique. The easiest way to do this is to come up with a 2 or 3 digit prefix, then add the last octet of the IP address, so RTSP would change from 554 to 12331 where the IP address of the camera was `*.*.*.31`, then the HTTP port could be 12431, and the Video port 12531